# Loop json in Expansion Tile

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm having big trouble trying to loop a json object inside a widget

I get this json from api call:

```
[
 {
  "id":21,
  "name":"John Smit",
  "date_birth":"30-09-1983",
  "cars":[
           {
            "id":406,
            "car_name":"Ford"
           }
          ]
 }
]
```

And a Model who get this data:

```
class Tiro {

  final int id;
  final String name;
  final String date_birth;
  final List cars;



  Tiro.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap) :

    id= jsonMap['id'],
    name= jsonMap['name'],
    date_birth= jsonMap['date_birth'],
    cars= jsonMap['cars'];

}
```

Now, I would display an ExtensionTile having like text the String name and inside his children some ListTile produced looping into List cars:

```
class TiroTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final Tiro _tiro;


  TiroTile(this._tiro);

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Card(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            ExpansionTile(
              title: Text(_tiro.name),
              leading: Icon(Icons.library_books,
              color: Colors.red[900],
              ),
              children: <Widget>[
                var myCars = jsonDecode(_tiro.cars);
                for (var s in myCars){
                  // here my ListTile
                }
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Of course it doesn't work, but I can't figure out how i can realize that.
Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a `Car` class just like the `Tiro` class which includes the `fromJson` constructor. The problem is that `jsonMap['cars']` returns a `List<dynamic>`. We need to convert this to a type `List` and then we need to serialize every single element inside this list. Hence you need to include the following changes -

```
var list = jsonMap['cars'] as List;
```

and inside the constructor you will do the following -

```
cars: list.map((i) => Car.fromJson(i)).toList()
```

Finally, looks something like this -

```
factory Tiro.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap){ // The way i have created the constructor is different, but it's upto you

    var list = jsonMap['cars'] as List;

    return Tiro(
      id : jsonMap['id'],
      name : jsonMap['name'],
      date_birth : jsonMap['date_birth'],
      cars: list.map((i) => Car.fromJson(i)).toList()
    );
  }
```

Also remove the `myCars` variable that you created, you don't have to decode the json after the above changes. You can access the list directly using `_tiro.cars`.

Additional -

Now, if your Json is a list of objects (as it seems from your example), you need to apply the similar logic. Create another class `TiroList` which has a field `List<Tiro> tiros`, and do the same thing mentioned above for serializing every singe Tiro.

Comment: Can you mark it as correctly answered, it will help someone who visits this question